# Convert Java Regex into PHP regex

Tags: java, php, regex, email

I got the following Java code from Apache commons to validate email addresses. I code in PHP so I'm trying to see if these regex can be used directly in PHP without any modification.

```
LEGAL_ASCII_REGEX = "^\\p{ASCII}+$";
EMAIL_REGEX = "^\\s*?(.+)@(.+?)\\s*$";
IP_DOMAIN_REGEX = "^\\[(.*)\\]$";
USER_REGEX = "^\\s*" + WORD + "(\\." + WORD + ")*$";
```

If an email address fails any of these 4 conditions above, then it would be considered invalid.

I don't have any experience with Java so any advice on modifications on these regex needed for PHP is hugely appreciated!

Best,

Update:

the code I'm using is:

```
        $email_to_test='www.jinfu66@foxmail.com';

        if(filter_var($email_to_test, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)&&preg_match('/^[[:ascii:]]+$/', $email_to_test)&&preg_match('/^\s*?(.+)@(.+?)\s*$/', $email_to_test))
        {
            echo 'It passed';
        }

        else
        {
            echo 'It did not t passs';
        }
```

I'm not sure how to add the condition that $email_to_test must match the requirement from $USER_REGEX in order for it to echo 'It passed'. Thank you!

2nd update:

Here's what WORD stands for in the original JAVA regex:

```
private static final String SPECIAL_CHARS = "\\p{Cntrl}\\(\\)<>@,;:'\\\\\\\"\\.\\[\\]";
private static final String VALID_CHARS = "[^\\s" + SPECIAL_CHARS + "]";
private static final String QUOTED_USER = "(\"[^\"]*\")";
private static final String WORD = "((" + VALID_CHARS + "|')+|" + QUOTED_USER + ")";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. PHP regex dont need double `\\` like Java regex
2. PCRE regex have `[[:ascii:]]` instead of `\\p{ASCII}`
3. PCRE regex need delimiter unlike Java regex

Following PHP regex should work for you:

```
$LEGAL_ASCII_REGEX = '/^[[:ascii:]]+$/';
$EMAIL_REGEX = '/^\s*?(.+)@(.+?)\s*$/';
$IP_DOMAIN_REGEX = '/^\[(.*)\]$/';
$USER_REGEX = '/^\s*' + preg_quote(WORD, '/') + '(\.' + preg_quote(WORD, '/') + ')*$/';
```

Comment: Huh, you converted 4 regexes, and no love...? +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81.... I guess since question got so many down votes that's why it lost visibility.

Comment: You're welcome. Now sure why you got so many down votes, I have neutralized one.

Comment: @anubhava I was able to implement the $Legal_ASCII_Regex and $EMAIL_REGEX without problem. However, I'm not sure how to implement the $USER_REGEX since it's 4 regex combined together. The forumla I'm using is preg_match('The regex to use', $the_value_to_test). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can take a look at your code. Post your code by editing question OR create an executable code sample on ideone.com

Comment: ok but which part of your code is not behaving? Also what should be value of `WORD` in `$USER_REGEX` ?

Comment: @anubhava the code in the update section is working fine but not complete. I would also need to make sure that $email_to_test matches the regex requirement $USER_REGEX. I've updated the question to specify what WORD stands for.

Comment: Is Java code running anywhere? Can you just print value of `WORD` to see its final value?